# Find horizontal line with maximum intersection segment distance between two circles

Tags: algorithm, geometry, distance, intersection

I'm trying to find the position of a line for which applies that the total the distance or length of the intersection all line segments with the two circles (potentially with different size) is maximum. What is the easiest way the determine the position of this line and the maximum length of all segments?

For example, the base case would be given two circles which are positioned with the same Y value. The optimal position for the line would be through the center of both circles.
In the image below the total maximum length the line's intersection segments with both circles would be `(diameter_left_circle + diameter_right_circle)`. Because if we move the line up or down, this total distance would decrease.

[image]

But let's say, the circles do not have a center with the same Y value, the horizontal line I'm searching for would be somewhere as shown in the image below. Because if we move up, the length of the intersecting line segment of left circle would increase, but for the right circle, it would decrease. And the sum of both would be smaller then the original situation. Vice versa we will end in the same situation.

[image]

Later, I would extend this solution with more circles. For example, the situation in the image below. It has the same two circle as in the second example, but an extra circle is added. We could find a line which intersect with the left circle and the new circle. However the total length of the segments would be smaller than the segments of the line that intersects the original left and right circle.

[image]

Comment: Does the line has to be horizontal? If you can draw any line on plave then for two circles you can always draw a line passing through their centers hence diameters add which is the max. However if you have three circles like in the extended case but you can draw a single line crossing both three then things start getting hairy.

Comment: Yes, the line has to be horizontal.

Comment: Express the sum of the lengths as a function of *y*, then find the maximum using Calculus 101 methods. This has nothing to do with programming.